# adding children to tree view node from an array issue

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add children to my treeview node. But its getting duplicate error.

```
                    const persons = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                      persons.push({ 
                          value: data[i].id, 
                          label: data[i].name,
                          
                          children: [
                          {  value: data[0].children[0].id,
                             label:data[0].children[0].name 
                            }
                          ]
                       }) 
                      } 
                      
                      this.setState({ persons });
```

error message is **CheckboxTreeError: Duplicate value '01-C11' detected. All node values must be unique.**

If I remove children then it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want the children data also to get from index instead of the first element?

In here?

```
children: [{  
    // Shouldn't the first 0 here be i ?
    value: data[0].children[0].id,
    label: data[0].children[0].name 
}]
```

Comment: yes you are right. I have changed it. Now its adding but its terminating if there is no children. I will try to fix it.